# Renumbering pages numbers after each group in a Microsoft Access report

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016, ms-access-reports

I have a MS report which has a header and footer on my grouping.  It has 70 pages with 14 different groups of varying sizes.  The first three groups - group 1 has Three (3) pages, group 2 has five (5) pages and the third group has nine (9) pages.  I want those pages to number like this (added a space to see the groups easier) 1,2,3, 1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 - so that with the first page of each group restarts at number 1.

When I add the following code to the footer of the group grouping:

```
Private Sub GroupFooter0_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
   'this fires 1 page early
   Me.Page = 1
End Sub
```

It fires one page early and gives the following 1,2,1, 2,3,4,1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1.

I am open to any thoughts and or solutions.

Comment: It might be easier to break it down in to 3 different calls to the report for each group. You can base the report off of queries. You make 3 queries, one for each group. Then you print off 3 report runs using each query as the source. Now you have three reports, based on groups, with correct page numbering.

Comment: Does this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reset-page-number-on-a-group-level

Comment: Thank you for the intial thought -I will ned something more scalable.  Yes I had seen this Microsoft link prior to reaching out to Over Stack and it did not solve my issue.  Thank you again for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common question. Too much code to post. Check out this link http://access.mvps.org/access/reports/rpt0013.htm
It uses arrays to reset the numbering.

Comment: Thank you for this link I had not seen it before.  I did add the code and a new problem arose.  I will make a new question for that problem.  Thank you again!